# Custom Segue Uncaught Exception Thrown

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

I'm using a segue and when the app is run and I click on the button it crashes and gives me an error saying `"Could not perform segue with identifier"`. This is the code that I control my segue with:

```
@IBAction func unwindToViewController (sender: UIStoryboardSegue){

}
let transitionManager = TransitionManager()

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // this gets a reference to the screen that we're about to transition to
    let toViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController

    // instead of using the default transition animation, we'll ask
    // the segue to use our custom TransitionManager object to manage the transition animation
    toViewController.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager

}
```

What could be wrong with my code that would do this? I have a whole swift file saying what the segue will do, which means that the custom segue is necessary.

This is my transition class, which the transition happens:
class TransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate  {

```
// MARK: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol methods

// animate a change from one viewcontroller to another
func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    // get reference to our fromView, toView and the container view that we should perform the transition in
    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
    let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

    // set up from 2D transforms that we'll use in the animation
    let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container!.frame.width, 0)
    let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container!.frame.width, 0)

    // start the toView to the right of the screen
    toView.transform = offScreenRight

    // add the both views to our view controller
    container!.addSubview(toView)
    container!.addSubview(fromView)

    // get the duration of the animation
    // DON'T just type '0.5s' -- the reason why won't make sense until the next post
    // but for now it's important to just follow this approach
    let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

    // perform the animation!
    // for this example, just slid both fromView and toView to the left at the same time
    // meaning fromView is pushed off the screen and toView slides into view
    // we also use the block animation usingSpringWithDamping for a little bounce
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {

        fromView.transform = offScreenLeft
        toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        }, completion: { finished in

            // tell our transitionContext object that we've finished animating
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

    })
}

// return how many seconds the transiton animation will take
func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return 0.5
}

// MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol methods

// return the animataor when presenting a viewcontroller
// remmeber that an animator (or animation controller) is any object that aheres to the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol
func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return self
}

// return the animator used when dismissing from a viewcontroller
func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return self
}
```

}

Comment: That is not your real code. Show your real code.

Comment: Also explain how the button is configured.

Comment: Dont rephrase you code or remove vital parts of, copy and paste it from the IDE in here.

Comment: Is the segue triggered in code or in a storyboard?

Comment: I've added all of the code that works with the segue.

Comment: I connect it via the storyboard but execute what happens in code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an `if` statement in to check for the `identifier`.

1. Make sure you have an identifier set in the Attributes Inspector in the main.storyboard
2. Updated code below:

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

       if (segue.identifier == "YOUR_IDENTIFIER_HERE") {

           let toViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
           toViewController.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager

       }

   }
   ```

Comment: There is no identifier set for my segue. Should there be one?

Comment: @iap-Software I would try it personally. Do you know where to set the identifier?

Comment: I know where to set it at but I'm not sure what the identifier it. Do you know what it is?

Comment: @iap-Software The identifier will be unique to that segue. So when you call to perform that seque, you can be sure the code will only run if that segue is the one thats called. If that makes sense?

Comment: Great. I added the code and when I ran it I now have this: A segue must either have a performHandler or it must override -perform.